# Probability for a vector x

Tags: machine-learning, probability, normal-distribution, probability-density

In machine learning suppose we have a GDA ([Gaussian Discriminant Analysis](https://www.metacademy.org/graphs/concepts/gaussian_discriminant_analysis)) model for classification.

If y can take values 0 or 1 and x represents the vector with n features(n x 1 dimensional)

What does p(x| y=0) or p(x|y=1) signify for a particular training example?
      x is actually a vector..how is conditional probability defined for this?
    Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say that *X<sub>0</sub>* is the set of vectors *x* that mapped to output 0, and *X<sub>1</sub>* is the set of vectors *x* that mapped to output 1. Take the mean of each set's vectors, and, similarly, [approximate the covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_of_covariance_matrices). 
Now build two [multivariate normal distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution), with these means and covariances, respectively.

Once you have these distribution, simply plug in the vector you want into the PDF to obtain its *density*. Note that since the probabilities are continuous, the *probability* about which you asked is 0, in general.

Comment: Yes, it would make sense, then.

Comment: Thanks.Could you kindly try and answer this when you're free.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32424497/log-likelihood-function-for-gdagaussian-discriminative-analysis

Comment: I'll try to do so tomorrow.