# Log likelihood function for GDA(Gaussian Discriminative analysis)

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, probability, gaussian

I am having trouble understanding the  likelihood function for GDA given in Andrew Ng's CS229 notes.

l(φ,µ0,µ1,Σ) = log (product from i to m) {p(x(i)|y(i);µ0,µ1,Σ)p(y(i);φ)}

The link is http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes2.pdf Page 5.

For Linear regression the function was product from i to m  p(y(i)|x(i);theta)
which made sense to me.
Why is there a change here saying it is given by p(x(i)|y(i) and that is multiplied by p(y(i);phi)?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The starting formula on page 5 is

```
l(φ,µ0,µ1,Σ) = log <product from i to m> p(x_i, y_i;µ0,µ1,Σ,φ)
```

leaving out the parameters `φ,µ0,µ1,Σ` for now, that can be simplified to

```
l = log <product> p(x_i, y_i)
```

using the chain rule you can convert that to either

```
l = log <product> p(x_i|y_i)p(y_i)
```

or

```
l = log <product> p(y_i|x_i)p(x_i).
```

In the page 5 formula, the `φ` is moved to `p(y_i)`, because only `p(y)` depends on it.

The likelihood starts with the joint probability distribution `p(x,y)` instead of the conditional probability distribution `p(y|x)`, which is why GDA is called a generative model (models from x to y and from y to x), while logistic regression is considered a discriminatory model (models from x to y, one-way). Both have their advantages and disadvantages. There seems to be a chapter about that further below.

Comment: Hi..given the traning set with x(vector maybe) and y values(0 or 1)..what does p(x_i,y_i) i.e the joint probability denssity function indicate...ie its meaning.In discriminative model i understood that in order to maximze the likelihood of theta..we maximized product from i to m p(y_i,x_i)..in this case the likelhood are for the parameters mu,phi and sigma.What does the joint pdf indicate here..

Comment: The [joint probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution) models the joint distribution over two (or more) random variables. E.g. if you know P(X,Y) you could estimate p(X=1, Y=0), p(X=15, Y=1), p(X=<any value>, Y=1) = p(Y=1), p(X=1, Y=<any value>), ... while in a conditional distribution P(Y|X) you don't know anything about the distribution of X. It's like somebody is handing you random X-values and all you can do is to tell the Y-value for them, i.e. you can't go "backwards" from y to the x.